# ∠C = 45° or 30°?

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, angle, pythagorean-triples

I tried to solve the following math problem using both 'Pythagorean Theorem' and 'Trigonometric Ratios' and I got different answers. No matter what method is followed, both answer should be the same. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Q. **In △ABC, ∠B = 90°. If AC = 2AB, then what is the value of ∠C?**

[I'm not allowed to add any images for some reason, please click here to see the triangle.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HORyv.png)

'**Pythagorean Theorem**' approach:

> *AC<sup>2</sup> = AB<sup>2</sup> + BC<sup>2</sup>
>
>   2AB<sup>2</sup> = AB<sup>2</sup> + BC<sup>2</sup> [since, AC = 2AB]
>
>   2AB<sup>2</sup> -  AB<sup>2</sup> = BC<sup>2</sup>
>
>   AB<sup>2</sup> = BC<sup>2</sup>
>
>   AB = BC* 
>   If AB = BC, then △ABC is an isosceles right triangle and **∠C = ∠B = 45°**.

**'Trigonometric Ratios'** approach:

> Suppose, ∠C = θ
>   sin θ = AB/AC
>   sin θ = AB/2AB [since, AC = 2AB]
>   sin θ = 1/2
>   sin θ = sin 30°
>   **θ = 30°**
>   So, **∠C = 30°**

Comment: When you substituted $AC=2AB$ into $AC^2 = AB^2 + BC^2$, the correct result is
$$
(2AB)^2 = AB^2 + BC^2
$$
So you forgot to square the factor $2$. The latter method is correct.

Comment: @MattiP. Don't know how I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: @MattiP. Could you please copy your comment and post it as an answer. It will help me to close this question.

Comment: Sine $30^\circ = 0.5$ and $\frac{AB}{AC}=0.5$ so $\angle C=30^\circ$

Comment: You have half an equilateral triangle so the answer is $30^\circ$.  If it was $45^\circ$ you would have half a square and the ratio of a leg to the hypotenuse would be $1:\sqrt{2}$ not $1:2$

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you substituted $AC=2AB$ into $AC^2 = AB^2 + BC^2$, the correct result is
$$
(2AB)^2 = AB^2 + BC^2
$$
So you forgot to square the factor $2$. The latter method is correct.

---

This is my 200th answer, by the way! Worth celebrating :)

Comment: wow!!! keep up the good work! 

Answer (score 3):

By Pythagora's theorem, we have: $$\overline{BC}=\sqrt{4\overline{AB}^2-\overline{AB}^2}=\sqrt{3\overline{AB}^2}\sqrt{3}\overline{AB}$$
Now we can caculate $\tan(C)$, so we have:
$$\tan(C)=\frac{\overline{AB}}{\overline{BC}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$$
From here we deduce that $C=\pi/6$ and $A=\pi/3$.

Note that in *Pythagora approach* your solution is not correct because you have to say $\overline{BC}^2=4\overline{AB}^2$ not $\overline{BC}=2\overline{BC}^2$

Comment: Why have you putted a $-1$? What's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I didn’t downvote the answer. Someone else did. There’s a typing mistake in the 3rd line from the top. Could you please check.

Comment: @Russel: yes, sorry. Corrected.

Answer (score 2):

It is a good practice to enclose the operand within brackets when operation is done on two or more terms.

$$ (2 AB)^2= 4 AB^2 \ne 2 AB^2 $$

Except this error all else you worked out is correct, and when actually corrected you get $ \angle A =60^{\circ},\angle B=30^{\circ}$ in both ways.

Comment: Thanks! I will keep this in mind.

Answer (score 1):

We prove the correct angle with no trigonometry:

Extend $\overline {AB}$ through $B$ to point $D$ such that $CD=AB$.  Then $\angle CBD$ is supplemental to $\angle CBA$ and thus measures $90°$.  This forces $\triangle ABC$ to be congruent with $\triangle DBC$.  Therefore their corresponding sides $\overline {CA}, \overline {CD}$ are also congruent, each measuring $2AB$.  By construction $BD=2AB$ as well rendering $\triangle ABD$ equilateral, therefore also equiangular.  Putting in the sum of interior angles equal to 180° then renders the measure of each individual angle, including $\angle A$, equal to 60°.  $\angle C$ is complementary to $\angle A$ and thu measures 30°.